# Obtain all Child Nodes of Specific Type Returns Nothing

Tags: c#, xml

I am attempting to get all the `Pit` XML elements from a `Drainage_String` XML node.

**My Problem:** When I go to retrieve all the `Pit` elements from the node, the XMLNodeList is always empty. I know that the node does contain 2 `Pit` elements so it should contain 2 node elements.

What is going wrong?

```
  XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
  xdoc.Load(xmlFilePath); 
  XmlNodeList xNodes = xdoc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("string_drainage");

  foreach (XmlNode dStr in xNodes) {
       XmlNodeList pits = dStr.SelectNodes("pit");
       MessageBox.Show("Num: "+pits.Count.ToString(), "Number"); 
       // always outputs "Num: 0"
  }
```

Example data I am using:

```
<string_drainage>
    <pit>
      <name>MH. </name>
      <ip>0</ip>
      <ratio>0</ratio>
      <x>212908.89268569</x>
      <y>612015.26122586</y>
      <z>80.62414621</z>
    </pit>
</string_drainage>
```

Detailed data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml12d xmlns="http://www.12d.com/schema/xml12d-10.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" language="English" version="1.0" date="2013-08-27" time="16:33:14" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.12d.com/schema/xml12d-10.0 http://www.12d.com/schema/xml12d-10.0/xml12d.xsd">
  <meta_data>
    <units>
      <metric>
        <linear>metre</linear>
        <area>square metre</area>
        <volume>cubic metre</volume>
        <temperature>celsius</temperature>
        <pressure>millibars</pressure>
        <angular>decimal degrees</angular>
        <direction>decimal degrees</direction>
      </metric>
    </units>
    <application>
      <name>12d Model</name>
      <manufacturer>12d Solutions Pty Ltd</manufacturer>
      <manufacturer_url>www.12d.com</manufacturer_url>
      <application>12d Model 10.0C1j</application>
      <application_build>10.1.10.22</application_build>
      <application_path>C:\Program Files\12d\12dmodel\10.00\nt.x64\12d.exe</application_path>
      <application_date_gmt>24-Jul-2013 02:18:30</application_date_gmt>
      <application_date>24-Jul-2013 12:18:30</application_date>
      <project_name>mjkhjk</project_name>
      <project_guid>{30A05217-706A-41c1-AF53-0D1A0975A5D0}</project_guid>
      <project_folder>C:\12djobs\mjkhjk</project_folder>
      <client>12d Training - NSW</client>
      <dongle>572d471062</dongle>
      <environment/>
      <env4d>C:\12d\10.00\user\env.4d</env4d>
      <user>Sam Zielke-Ryner</user>
      <export_file_name>Tttt.xml</export_file_name>
      <export_date_gmt>27-Aug-2013 06:33:14</export_date_gmt>
      <export_date>27-Aug-2013 16:33:14</export_date>
    </application>
  </meta_data>
  <comments>
    <manufacturer>12d Solutions Pty Ltd</manufacturer>
    <manufacturer_url>www.12d.com</manufacturer_url>
    <application>12d Model 10.0C1j</application>
    <application_build>10.1.10.22</application_build>
    <application_path>C:\Program Files\12d\12dmodel\10.00\nt.x64\12d.exe</application_path>
    <application_date_gmt>24-Jul-2013 02:18:30</application_date_gmt>
    <application_date>24-Jul-2013 12:18:30</application_date>
    <export_file_name>Tttt.xml</export_file_name>
    <export_date_gmt>27-Aug-2013 06:33:14</export_date_gmt>
    <export_date>27-Aug-2013 16:33:14</export_date>
  </comments>
  <string_drainage>
    <name/>
    <time_created>29-Jul-2013 02:02:03</time_created>
    <time_updated>29-Jul-2013 02:02:11</time_updated>
    <outfall>null</outfall>
    <flow_direction>1</flow_direction>
    <use_pit_con_points>false</use_pit_con_points>
    <data_3d>
      <p>212908.89268569 612015.26122586 0</p>
      <p>212715.09268598 612007.24091243 84.20896044</p>
    </data_3d>
    <pit>
      <name>MH. </name>
      <type>CONC COVER</type>
      <road_name/>
      <road_chainage>null</road_chainage>
      <diameter>1.1</diameter>
      <con_point_mode>Points</con_point_mode>
      <floating>true</floating>
      <hgl>null</hgl>
      <chainage>0</chainage>
      <ip>0</ip>
      <ratio>0</ratio>
      <x>212908.89268569</x>
      <y>612015.26122586</y>
      <z>80.62414621</z>
    </pit>
    <pit>
      <name>MH. </name>
      <type>CONC COVER</type>
      <road_name/>
      <road_chainage>null</road_chainage>
      <diameter>1.1</diameter>
      <con_point_mode>Points</con_point_mode>
      <floating>true</floating>
      <hgl>null</hgl>
      <chainage>193.96588699</chainage>
      <ip>1</ip>
      <ratio>0</ratio>
      <x>212715.09268598</x>
      <y>612007.24091243</y>
      <z>84.20896044</z>
    </pit>
    <pipe>
      <name>A</name>
      <type>PVC</type>
      <diameter>0.15</diameter>
      <nominal_diameter>0.15</nominal_diameter>
      <us_level>77.38411559</us_level>
      <ds_level>79.32377446</ds_level>
      <us_hgl>0</us_hgl>
      <ds_hgl>0</ds_hgl>
      <flow_velocity>0</flow_velocity>
      <flow_volume>0</flow_volume>
      <attributes>
        <real>
          <name>nominal diameter</name>
          <value>0.15</value>
        </real>
        <real>
          <name>calculated critical cover chainage</name>
          <value>4.31482574</value>
        </real>
      </attributes>
    </pipe>
  </string_drainage>
</xml12d>
```

Comment: There's some piece of the puzzle missing here. Is that the entire contents of your xml file? Is that your true root node?

Comment: Typically these issue are related to having the incorrect node when starting your search. @user1 is correct in saying if the example xml isn't the fully xml, then your code will be based on the incorrect node. In fact the error is earlier in your code, xNodes my have zero elements.

Comment: @user1 Thanks for the comment. Please see update for complete xml file contents

Comment: @Jason I've tested to see I have the correct (& only) string_drainage by printing out the dStr's inner XML. Its indeed the right node.

Comment: @VhsPiceros did a test and its not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to SelectNodes requires the default namespace to be added to it.

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", xdoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
XmlNodeList pits = dStr.SelectNodes("x:pit");
```

Refer to the help located [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.XML.XMLNODE.SELECTNODES%29;k%28SELECTNODES%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

A tip I use for xml files is to always have namespaces aliased in xml files I use. Otherwise its harder to write xpath references to them.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you

test.xml is a copy/paste of your xml

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load(@"c:\test.xml");
        XmlNodeList xNodes = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("pit");
        Console.WriteLine("Num: " + xNodes.Count.ToString());

        foreach (XmlNode dStr in xNodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + dStr.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText);
            Console.WriteLine("ip: " + dStr.SelectSingleNode("ip").InnerText);
            Console.WriteLine("ratio: " + dStr.SelectSingleNode("ratio").InnerText);
            Console.WriteLine("X: " + dStr.SelectSingleNode("z").InnerText);
            Console.WriteLine("Y: " + dStr.SelectSingleNode("y").InnerText);
            Console.WriteLine("X: " + dStr.SelectSingleNode("x").InnerText);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that it will select all the pits not just the pits inside a specific `string_drainage` node

Answer (score -1):

maybe is better use XmlNode and XmlSingleNode of Xmldocument